# SlickJS function working only on one slide

Tags: javascript

I'm using slick js to display items by slide. Each slide has 1 bigger featured image and 3 smaller thumbnails.

When a thumbnail is hovered, the class of 'thumbnail-active' is added, removing it from the previous one, and the thumbnail gets displayed as a featured image.

The problem is that this is working only on the first slide. I've tried to get the current slide and reapply the function each time the slide is changed, but it didn't seem to work.
Is there other way of doing it?

Here is the js:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="slide-wrapper">
        <img class="thumbnail thumbnail-active" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4937452/pexels-photo-4937452.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4937448/pexels-photo-4937448.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4937360/pexels-photo-4937360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
    </div>
    <img id="featured" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4937452/pexels-photo-4937452.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
</div>

let thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail')
let activeImages = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail-active')

for (var i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
    thumbnails[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        if (activeImages.length > 0) {
            activeImages[0].classList.remove('thumbnail-active')
        }
        this.classList.add('thumbnail-active')
        document.getElementById('featured').src = this.src
    })
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6c2f9gs/)

Comment: check your fiddle and find there is an issue with #id duplication, you have the same id named `featured`, you need to address it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace the id `#featured` with `.featured`and then try the replace the code with the below line

```
//document.getElementById('featured').src = this.src; //old code
this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.featured').src  = this.src; // new line
```

Answer (score 0):

@Onkar is right. its because of duplicate id.

you can do:

```
  document.querySelector('.slick-current #featured').src = this.src;
```

slick will add a class called **slick-current** to current slide.

its better to replace #featured with .featured in your script and use featured **as** **class and not id**.